# AutoRefineV not picking up explicit inference from Map?

Tags: scala, refinement-type

I have a refined type definition like this:

```
type D = String Refined Regex "(a|b)"
```

I can use the refinement in a single line expressing the value but for some reason `autoRefineV` is not picking it up when used in the context of a Map, even if the type is explicit. For example:

```
import eu.timepit.refined.auto.autoRefineV
val test1: D = "a" // this is fine
val test2 = Map[D, String]("a" -> "test") // this fails
val test3: Map[D, String] = Map("a" -> "test") // this also fails
val test4 = Map(test1 -> "test") // this works!
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
found : (String, String)
required : (D, String)
```

So for some reason, the value is not being auto-converted from a string to a `D` type? Do I need to define a refined object of type `Map[D, String]`? Do I need to use a witness (which I have no idea how to use)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an implicit conversion from `String` to `D`, but definitions of `test2/3` would need one from `(String, String)` to `(D, String)` which doesn't exist.

```
val test5 = Map(("a": D) -> "test")
```

should work if you just want to write it in one line.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it was something like that. I'll try to write an implicit that does that. I need something that converts `String -> D`, right?

Comment: Follow up question, why doesn't scala recognize the key as type `D`? Even if I explicitly specify the type? `Map[D, String]`?

Comment: "I need something that converts String -> D, right?" `autoRefineV` already does that (with additional implicit arguments). You'd need to "lift" it to pairs.

Comment: "why doesn't scala recognize the key as type D?" Because what you do with `"a"` is call `->` on it. That method exists on any type (due to a different implicit conversion), and Scala doesn't have any reason to apply a implicit conversion to `D` before calling it. (If it did, that would be 2 separate implicit conversions which it won't even look for anyway.)